# Small wire pulled from ac unit. Unit turns on, but the fan doesn't

Tags: wiring

My unit wasn't putting out cold air
I looked outside and the small wire that leads from the house to the unit is pulled from the back of the unit where do I connect that wire? I can hear the compressor click on but the fan won't turn on

Comment: What make and model is your AC unit, and can you post photos of the pulled-out wire + the wiring diagram of the unit?

Comment: Use google to get a wiring diagram of the make and model of your unit.  From the little information you gave us makes it impossible to know.